# AJAX callbacks replace with Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

The code below works fine without using Promise. But I am also learning `Promise`. I would like to request if continue using `Existing Codes` is feasible for the long run as I can very well manage my callbacks or should I try adapting the `Promise` logic.

Also, using Promise, my code does not work, so help in the `NEW CODES WITH PROMISES` section will highly be appreciated.

**EXISTING CODES**

```
var init = function () {
    getFirstFunction(() => getSecondFunction(() => {

    }));
};

function getFirstFunction(callback) {
$.getAjax('urlGoesHere', function (response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
       //do whatever you want do with your response.data
       if (callback) { callback(); }
      }
    else {}
});
}

function getSecondFunction(callback) {
$.getAjax('listHelper/getSites', function (response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        //do whatever you want do with your response.data
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    } else {
    }
});
}

AJAX SCRIPT
window.$.getAjax = function (url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            success(response, function () {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(response);
                }
            });
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
};
```

**NEW CODES WITH PROMISES**

```
function getFirstFunction(callback) {
$.getAjax('urlGoesHere', function (response)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    if(callback) callback();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
});
}


AJAX SCRIPT
window.$.getAjax = function (url, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      .....
      success: function (response) {
            success(response, function () {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(resolve(response));
                }
            });
        }
....
    });
});
};
```

Comment: `$.ajax()` already returns a promise. (It's actually a jQuery `Deferrred`, but these act like promises.)

Comment: @Barmar I was trying to follow this https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-promisify-an-ajax-call/ . If Ajax returns a promise then all these web sites are simply screwing us.

Comment: Because they didn't realize it.

Comment: You're not **returning** the promise from `$.ajax`. Also, the "should you" part of the question is off-topic for SO. You should if you want to, you can, and your team is happy with it. You shouldn't if you don't want to, can't, or your team is not happy with it.

Comment: Side note: I would use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) rather than using `$.ajax` in new code. Just beware of the API footgun: You have to check the `ok` property on the response you get before you try to read it.